# Best performance comparing to string.Empty (c#)

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any difference between

```
if(string.Empty.Equals(text))
```

and

```
if(text.Equals(string.Empty))
```

concerning performance, unexpected behaviour or readability?

Comment: what did your test show? and does it really matter? it's very unlikely to ever be a bottleneck (unless you're sorting/searching or similar in which case youød still need to profile first and the you'd have your answer)

Comment: what about `String.IsNullOrEmpty(text)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These will have the same performance characteristics.

If `text` is `null`, your second line with throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Personally I find:

```
if(text == string.Empty)
```

More readable than either your options.

And there are the built in:

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
```

And for .NET 4.0:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(text))
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
{
}
```

as I think it's more readable, which is the most important here IMO (actually the result won't be the same for `null` values, but your second version would throw an exception for this particular test case).

I don't know if there is any difference in the generated IL, but in any case, such a micro-optimization (if any...) will clearly not make your application faster.

---

EDIT:

Just tested it as I'm curious:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch z1 = new Stopwatch();
    Stopwatch z2 = new Stopwatch();
    Stopwatch z3 = new Stopwatch();

    int count = 100000000;

    string text = "myTest";

    z1.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        if (string.Empty.Equals(text))
        {
            tmp++;
        }
    }
    z1.Stop();

    z2.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        if (text.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            tmp++;
        }
    }
    z2.Stop();

    z3.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        int tmp = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            tmp++;
        }
    }
    z3.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Method 1: {0}", z1.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Method 2: {0}", z2.ElapsedMilliseconds));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Method 3: {0}", z3.ElapsedMilliseconds));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Not sure the test is relevant because testing micro-optimizations is always more complicated than it looks, but here are some results:

```
Method 1: 611
Method 2: 615
Method 3: 336
```

Method 1 and 2 are identical as expected, and method 3, the more readable solution IMO, looks like the fastest one, so make your choice ;)

Answer (score 5):

Concerning performance they will behave the same. Concerning unexpected behavior, the second might throw a `NullReferenceException` if text = null. `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))` seems more natural though to achieve the same thing (same performance, same result) without the undesired unexpected behavior and the possibility of a NRE.

Answer (score 4):

They are the equivalent.

First case:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
IL_0006: ldarg.0
IL_0007: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.String::Equals(string)
IL_000c: ldc.i4.0
IL_000d: ceq
IL_000f: stloc.0
IL_0010: ldloc.0
IL_0011: brtrue.s <target>
```

Second case:

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: ldsfld string [mscorlib]System.String::Empty
IL_0007: callvirt instance bool [mscorlib]System.String::Equals(string)
IL_000c: ldc.i4.0
IL_000d: ceq
IL_000f: stloc.0
IL_0010: ldloc.0
IL_0011: brtrue.s <target>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no performance difference in this case. It's like comparing "x==y" to "y==x".

I'd say that `if (text == string.Empty)` is the most readable syntax, but that's just me.

Of course, you could also use `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) { }`, or `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text)`.

As for unexpected behavior, it's a pretty straightforward string comparison. I can't imagine how you'd get unexpected behavior out of it.